Maintain position in terminal command history on macOS?
I enter many commands into the terminal.  I enter command a, then b, then c, etc.  I'm on command g now but I want to execute a, then b, then c, again.
I press up (g), up (f), up (e), up (d), up (c), up (b), up (a), then enter to execute a.  I have to press up 7 times again to get to and execute b.  Same for c.
On Windows, I maintain my position in the command history.  So once I get to command a and press enter, I just press up maybe twice to get to b, and maybe twice again to get to c.  This makes repeating sequences easier, obviously.  The terminal apparently stays at its HEAD position, relative to history.
How can the macOS terminal be reconfigured to maintain its position in the command history?

Looks like you're after the accept-line-and-down-history widget bound to Ctrl+o in emacs mode by default.
So that should be just a matter of pressing Ctrl+o instead of Enter. Or add:
bindkey '\C-M' accept-line-and-down-history

To your ~/.zshrc if you want that behaviour for Enter.
Or:
zle -A accept-line-and-down-history accept-line

To make accept-line (the widget bound to Enter by default) an Alias for the accept-line-and-down-history, changing the behaviour of all keys bound to accept-line or that invoke accept-line as part of some other widget.

That works!  Thank you.
